# Windows test if BLE device is currenlty connected using SetupAPI in C

Tags: c, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, setupapi

I'm trying to discover if a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device, that has been paired previously, is currently enabled using setupAPI in a C program with minGW compiler. At the moment I'm trying to use setupAPI SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW() function for property DEVPKEY_Device_IsPresent but the result is always true even if the BLE device is currently switched off. The property DEVPKEY_DeviceContainer_IsConnected produces an error code 1168. Does anyone have done something similar already?

The relevant console output for my device:

```
SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME: Testdevice
The device is present.
Failed to get connn property: 1168
Failed to get paired property: 1168
```

The output has been generated by the following test c program.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <devpkey.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <bthdef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData;
        devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

        // Create a device information set of Bluetooth devices
        hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_BLUETOOTH, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT);

        if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        {
            printf("Error getting device information set: %lu\n", GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

        // Enumerate through devices in the set
        for (DWORD i = 0; SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i, &devInfoData); i++)
        {
            DEVPROPTYPE dataType;
            DWORD requiredSize;

            SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &devInfoData, SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME, &dataType, NULL, 0, &requiredSize);

            LPTSTR deviceDescription = (LPTSTR)malloc(requiredSize);
            if (SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &devInfoData, SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME, &dataType, (PBYTE)deviceDescription, requiredSize, NULL))
            {
                // Print device description
                printf(("SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME: %s\n"), deviceDescription);
            }
            else
            {
                printf(("Error SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME information. Error %d\n"), GetLastError());
            }
            free(deviceDescription);

            UCHAR present;
            if(SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW(hDevInfo, &devInfoData, &DEVPKEY_Device_IsPresent, &dataType, (PBYTE)&present, sizeof(present), NULL, 0))
            {
                if (dataType == DEVPROP_TYPE_BOOLEAN && present) {wprintf(L"The device is present.\n");} else {wprintf(L"The device is not present.\n");}
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Failed to get present property: %lu\n", GetLastError());
            }

            UCHAR connn;
            if(SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW(hDevInfo, &devInfoData, &DEVPKEY_DeviceContainer_IsConnected, &dataType, (PBYTE)&connn, sizeof(connn), NULL, 0))
            {
                if (dataType == DEVPROP_TYPE_BOOLEAN && connn) {wprintf(L"The device is connn.\n");} else {wprintf(L"The device is not connn.\n");}
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Failed to get connn property: %lu\n", GetLastError());
            }


            UCHAR paired;
            if(SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW(hDevInfo, &devInfoData, &DEVPKEY_DeviceContainer_IsPaired, &dataType, (PBYTE)&paired, sizeof(paired),  NULL, 0))
            {
                if (dataType == DEVPROP_TYPE_BOOLEAN && paired) {wprintf(L"The device is paired.\n");} else {wprintf(L"The device is not paired.\n");}
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Failed to get paired property: %lu\n", GetLastError());
            }
        }

        // Clean up
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfo);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, my Bluetooth Framework can check is BLE device is connected. And, of course, it can disconnect it even if connection made by other application. However, it is done not with Setup API.